# How to re-open a minimized Tauri application with Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: reactjs, rust, tauri

I am building a small application with Tauri (React). I am unable to open the application when it is minimized.

```
const handleKeyPress = useCallback(async (event: any) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "t") {
      // Minimize the window
      await appWindow.minimize();
    } else if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "w") {
      await appWindow.hide();
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
    };
  }, [handleKeyPress]);
```

This is how I can minimize with a shortcut. But unable to setFocus to the minimized app and reopen it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the document no longer has focus when it's minimized, it's unable to listen for `KeyDown` events. Luckily Tauri has the means to register global shortcuts via its [globalShortcut](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/globalshortcut/) API. Your code may look something like this:

```
import { registerAll } from "@tauri-apps/api/globalShortcut";
import { appWindow } from "@tauri-apps/api/window";
import { useEffect } from "react";

/*...*/

useEffect(() => {
  const registerShortCuts = async () => {
    await registerAll(["t", "w"], async (shortcut) => {
      if (shortcut === "t") await appWindow.minimize();
      else await appWindow.unminimize();
    });
  };

  registerShortCuts();
}, []);
```

You may want to make your shortcuts more complex so that they do not interfere with the normal use of other applications.

Answer (score 1):

For tauri 2.x:

Add shortcut plugin to Cargo.toml:

```ini
tauri-plugin-global-shortcut = "v2.0.0-beta.2"
```

Then call it inside your app builder in `lib.rs`

```rust
.plugin(tauri_plugin_global_shortcut::Builder::new().build())
```

Add `npm` library:

```bash
npm install @tauri-apps/plugin-global-shortcut
```

Add the listener:

```js
import { registerAll } from '@tauri-apps/plugin-global-shortcut';

await registerAll(['t','w'], (shortcut) => {
  console.log(`Shortcut ${shortcut} triggered`);
});
```

And don't forget to set capabilities inside `src-tauri/capabilities/main.json`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "../gen/schemas/desktop-schema.json",
  "identifier": "main-capability",
  "description": "Capability for the main window",
  "windows": ["main"],
  "permissions": [
    "global-shortcut:allow-is-registered",
    "global-shortcut:allow-register",
    "global-shortcut:allow-unregister"
  ]
}
```